# Before_filter for rails 3?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

According to what I'm [reading in the docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Filters/ClassMethods/before_filter), the `before_filter` method is deprecated.

This question is two-fold: First, is that correct (It doesn't work in Rails 3, so I'm pretty sure it is) and second, what is another way to replicate that method just with using Rails/Ruby's built-in methods?

From what I can find, there isn't anything like it, but I *could* be looking in the wrong place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Rails 4.2's changelogs mention that all `*_filter` methods are going away in favor of their `*_action` counterparts.](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_2_release_notes.html#action-pack-notable-changes)

Versions up to Rails 4.2 can use `before_filter` as they please. Versions 4.2 and above should use `before_action` (and friends) instead.

Comment: To elaborate: the Rails API documentation isn't built by hand. Instead, the Rails devs put the documentation in comments above the methods they write, and the documentation-generating tools pick up on it. However, `before_filter` and similar methods are now being built dynamically, which the doc tools do *not* pick up on. It's a bit awkward, but that's how it goes :/

Comment: according to rails, they plan to remove before_filter sometime in the future. as of 4.2, they removed documentation.

Comment: Thanks @dtc, I've updated this with a link to the documentation.

Comment: cool, great! im actually curious if there's a "stack overflow" with patch/version update support since its probably hard to look for the "latest" notes when libraries and frameworks get updated.

Comment: Well, I think that boils down to knowing the history of Rails and when specific versions were released. The original answer for this was at the end of Aug 2011, and that's roughly when Rails 3.1 was released. So therefore you should be reading the answer within the context of that knowledge... unless it's edited to mention a more recent version.